# Turn-based Pencil/paper game; phases

Tags: turn-based-strategy

I'm not entirely sure this is the right place since all I see is coding questions, but I'll ask anyway in the hopes that someone can answer or point me in the right direction.

I've been developing a pencil/paper war strategy game for a while now and have run multiple tests with other players, but I've been having one major issue with the action system.

The game is turn-based and phase-based during the turns. Each turn has 7 phases and each unit has anywhere between 1 and 7 phases, depending on the unit itself. The phases are split up for the turn phase, so a unit with a movement phase can only move on the x; |x|2|x|4|x|6|x|.

I have a separation of attack phases and movement phases which can be two different things. For example, a vehicle has a movement rating of 6 but an attack of 4. This means it can move 6 times and attack only 4 times but only on it's designated rating.

Hopefully that's enough explanation... Anyway, I have had an issue when it comes to initiative. If two units have an attack on the exact same part of the phase and both deal enough damage to destroy each other... How could I determine who attacked who first? Should one unit be able to destroy the other, or should both just destroy each other?

The second part of that would be... If both units still have the same attack phase and unit 1 deals enough damage to destroy the other but unit 2 only deals a small amount... Who went first? Should there be a dice roll or coin toss to determine or can someone help think of a way to fix this?

Comment: [Technically tabletop game questions are not on-topic here (something I didn't realize myself!)](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2804/39518), but since the mechanical issue you describe also applies to turn-based digital games I don't think the question needs to be closed. [You might find more tabletop-focused users on the Card & Board Game SE though](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Getting into your actual question: what "should" happen in a game is determined by the game designer, according to what meets the goals of the game's creative direction. For each of the possibilities you describe, we can name a game where the designer chose to have it work that way. So there's no global "correct" answer here - it depends on the kind of game experience you want to create. Randomness can inject uncertainty and drama, but also frustration, or (when players have to physically roll dice) complexity and slowdown. Whether that's the right trade for your game depends on your goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see three approaches for this. Which one is better, is up to you. Although, what do player say? Player feedback is probably more valuable than, you know, some random person on the Internet feedback.

1. Simultaneous initiative: They both attack, and they both receive damage. That would mean that both players declare the attack, and then you solve the consequences for both attacks. If one unit destroys the other, that does not prevent the attack of the destroyed unit to also deal damage. If they can both destroy each other, they both get destroyed.
2. Ad-Hoc Initiative. Just pick one at random when the situation arrives.
3. Global Initiative. Usually some order of play is picked at the start of the game. *Perhaps by throwing dice and picking in descending order. Or some other randomization strategy.* You don't have that, consider adding it. If you do have it, consider reusing it for deciding who attacks first.

I would prefer the first approach. It keeps the spirit of simultaneous actions, does not require additional mechanical complexity, and can lead to unique outcomes that are impossible (such as mutual destruction) if we decide that one unit goes first.

The second approach has value from the point of view of risk and reward. If the units can destroy each other, the attack is a gamble, and the player should be ready for both winning and losing.

The third approach can have some strategic value. Given that the outcome is known, you can plan ahead for it. However… The first player would not attack a unit knowing the other player can answer back and win. And the second player would not answer the attack known it will be a lose. That means, that this approach should (in perfect play) result in the mutual attack never happening. *On the other there could be strategic value in getting a mutual destruction with the first approach, which I consider more interesting.*

Although, we should also consider what else can the other player do other than response the attack. Given that the game is divided in phases, and some are designated attack phases. The other player cannot move while being attacked. It appears to me the only other option is to attack a third unit. Then again, the same arguments above would unroll. If the player know they are winning or losing despite what they might do, it is not an interesting decision… However, if they had another option aside from attacking, it could be.

---

Being a pencil and paper game, you really have much more freedom. The player can play rock-paper-scissors, or they ask each other trivia questions, or whatever. The answer above applies for video and otherwise games. *Well, I guess you could implement rock-paper-scissors et.al. as a solution in a video game. Let us say, this is not an exhaustive list of possible solutions.*

---

Considering units that can move and attack in the same phase. We can continue to apply the rule of all attacks happening at the same time. However, if we want to simulate the idea that all units begin the phase at the same time, then a unit that did not move would attack before one that did.

We can come up with more complicated rules for the case where both units did attack and move. Namely, that the faster unit (the one able to move more more distance) would attack first.

Similarly, we could solve initiative based on the attacks. That is, adding an initiative stat to either units or attack (or even both, and add them together). Then you compare these values to decide who attacks first.

*This kind of solutions I would avoid in pencil and paper games, just to keep the flow of the game fast, however you see these kind of rules all the time in tabletop RPG games and similar. And of course, for a video game, we can disregard the time this computation would take.*

---

See also [En passant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant) chess rule. Where a pawn that moved later can capture a pawn that moved the prior turn "as it was passing". As if, the turns of both player somehow overlapped in time. While not exactly the same thing, it is an interesting precedent that might serve as inspiration.